# Magento2 how to convert city and state name in arabic language on checkout payment page

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, inline-translations

I want to convert the city and state name into the Arabic language on the checkout/#payment page.

Here I attached an image where I want to convert the city and state names.
https://i.imgur.com/cIOzmEN.png
so can tell me in which file is the effect that and how to get city and state names in the Arabic language?